# Topology on group induced from subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, number-theory

The topology on the Weil group $W_K$ is the one for which the inertia subgroup $I_K$ (with its topology?) is open. But what exactly does this mean? $I_K$ inherits its topology from the absolute Galois group $G_K$ of a local field $K$. So how does the topology on $W_K$, which is not the subspace topology from $G_K$, look like? A subset $U\subset W_K$ is open iff $U \cap I_K$ is open in $I_K$? I have often encountered such situations where one defines the topology on a group or ring or whatever by declaring some special subgroup/subring/ideal/... to be open. But I do not quite understand what the new topology on the bigger group/ring/... is (in this case $W_K$).

Answer (score 1):

If $\Phi \in \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ is any Frobenius element, the Weil group $W_K$ is equal to

$$\{ \phi \Phi^n : \phi \in I_K, n \in \mathbb Z \}.$$

where each element $\phi \Phi^n$ has unique expression (depending on $\Phi$).  The choice of a Frobenius element $\Phi$ therefore gives a bijection of sets (not a group isomorphism)

$$W_K \rightarrow I_K \times \mathbb Z$$

and the topology on $W_K$ is defined to be the product topology (with $I_K$ has its usual profinite topology and $\mathbb Z$ is discrete).  This topology is independent of the choice of $\Phi$.

So the open sets of $W_K$ are unions of sets of the form  $U \Phi^n$, for $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $U \subset I_K$ open.

Note the inclusion map $W_K \subset \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ is continuous with dense image, even though $W_K$ does not have the subspace topology.